# Why this script doesn't work in cron and generates a empty output?

Tags: root, cron, output

Why this script doesn't work in the cron for root or other user and generates a empty output ?

```
/tmp/test-1.log
---------------
#!/bin/sh
/bin/echo this is test-1.sh
/bin/date "+%FT%T"
```

Permissions are ok

```
# ls -l /root/test-*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 58 Apr 27 22:48 /root/test-1.sh
#
```

Cron line `crontab -e`. I had tried these 2 ways, creating and appending

```
55 * * * * /root/test-1.sh &>  /tmp//tmp/test-1.log
58 * * * * /root/test-1.sh &>> /tmp//tmp/test-2.log
```

and output is empty, why !!!!!!

```
# date; ls -ld /tmp/test*
Sun Apr 27 22:59:56 CEST 2014
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 27 22:55 /tmp/test-1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 27 22:55 /tmp/test-2.log
#
```

**What's it wrong ?**
It must be something simple but I cann't found it.

By the way I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.

Comment: thanks to girardengo and L. D. James, you are right.
The right syntax for redirecting stdout and stderr to a file is:
`
    55 * * * * /root/test-1.sh >  /tmp//tmp/test-1.log 2>&1
    58 * * * * /root/test-1.sh >> /tmp//tmp/test-2.log 2>&1
`
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line in the crontab with this:

```
55 * * * * /bin/sh /root/test-1.sh > /tmp/test-1.log
58 * * * * /bin/sh /root/test.2.sh >> /tmp/test-2.log
```

this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect syntax is flawed.

Change your crontab to:

```
55 * * * * /root/test-1.sh >  /tmp/test-1.log
58 * * * * /root/test-1.sh >> /tmp/test-2.log
```

Comment: I see girardengo has given you the answer while I was testing the output.  But as he mentioned, the updated lines will work.